# Dynamics CRM Subgrid Advanced Find

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Can Advanced Find be added to a sub-grid?
I have a need to add multiple (potentially all or very many) records to a sub-grid all at once.

Is there another way to add, say 5000, records to a sub-grid or let the user choose 5000 records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a one-off task or something that will need to be carried out regularly?

If one-off, then configuring an On Demand workflow and using the [Workflow Execution Manager](https://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation#workflowexecutionmanager) of the MSCRMToolkit would do it.  Define your FetchXML through Advanced Find, plumb it into this app and away you go.

If it is something that could need to be carried out regularly, then you're looking at HTML Web Resources and REST services behind it.  There's nothing out-of-the-box to do this sort of thing.

Comment: It is for one entity, but the user is to choose the Contacts to associate.